# Rendering a Component in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Small Query, I tried to google it but couldn't find the solution.

When a React Component state is changed(useState()), so the whole page is rendered or that specific React Component is rendered like in Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Only the component will be rendered again.

Answer (score 0):

The useState will render all the components associated with it, meaning if you put the useState in the parent component it will also re-render the children component.

Answer (score 0):

When State changes in the child component do not affect the parent component, but when a parent component's state changes, all  child components are rendered.